# Access Data stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssma

I'm currently working on a project to convert our Access Apps to store the table data in SQL Server.

Using SSMA to migrate the data results in the foreign keys and Look-ups work as expected in Access when completed. However, if I import & link directly from SQL Server back to Access, the foreign key look-ups do not work.

The only difference I can determine in the links is, the ones SSMA created do not specify a DSN and the ones I manually created do.

I'm hopefully someone might have run into this in the past and might have some insight.

*We are migrating from Access 2013 to SQL Server 2012.*

Answer (score 1):

I finally determined the lookups have the be setup in Access, they won't automatically be created when attaching a sql server table as a link.

Comment: You can accept your answer so that this question can be closed.